# How do you get the button to print the state before you click it?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

If you run the code below, you will find that it will say "checked" after you press it, but is it possible when you run it that it starts off with "not checked" because that's the state it is in before you press it? I'd like to use this for an auto script and it should be on because I store the status of the checkbox in Chrome, so when it is on, it should be on rather than having to check it off and on again to turn it on.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  var checkbox = document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]');

  checkbox.addEventListener('change', function () {
    if (checkbox.checked) {
      // do this
      console.log('Checked');
    } else {
      // do that
      console.log('Not checked');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {display:none;}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}
```

```html
<h2>Toggle Switch</h2>

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <div class="slider"></div>
</label>
```

Comment: On your JS file, if you have any function that performs as a constructor or function that initializing the values, you can have one `console.log` that will print the initial value, it will be called once and from there on the print continues as programed currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the if-block inside it's own function - e.g. `isChecked()` - and call it in two places:

- inside the onChange event callback handler
- right after the listener has been added or generally the button has been set up to query the current state of the button

Here's an example:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var checkbox = document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]');

    function isChecked() {
      if (checkbox.checked) {
        // do this
        console.log('Checked');
      } else {
        // do that
        console.log('Not checked');
      }
    }
    checkbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
      isChecked();
    });

    isChecked();

  }

);
```

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {
  display: none;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}
```

```html
<h2>Toggle Switch</h2>

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <div class="slider"></div>
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do this to run your checked/not checked code at load time:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  var checkbox = document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]');

  function showState () {
    if (checkbox.checked) {
      // do this
      console.log('Checked');
    } else {
      // do that
      console.log('Not checked');
    }
  }

  checkbox.addEventListener('change', showState);

  // run showState on load
  showState();
});
```